# solr - prevent changes until full commit

Tags: apache, solr, documents

I have a solr setup with lacks of documents.
My problem is
during commit partial change visible on front-end e.g. if 2000 documents are committed front-end will show only 2000 documents, after some time 5k, 10k...until full commit is completed.

I want this behavior to change, change should be visible only after full commit, till full commit is completed, solr should use old index/data.

Answer (score 0):

Solr uses notion of Near Real Time Searching.

I have not changed defaults before but you need to look into this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching

Answer (score 0):

In your Solr (4)'s [solrconfig.xml](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml), there is (or could be) a section called autoCommit

```
    <autoCommit>
       <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs> <!-- maximum uncommited docs before autocommit triggered -->
       <maxTime>15000</maxTime> <!-- maximum time (in MS) after adding a doc before an autocommit is triggered -->
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> <!-- SOLR 4.0.  Optionally don't open a searcher on hard commit.  This is useful to minimize the size of transaction logs that keep track of uncommitted updates. -->
    </autoCommit>
```

I read your question that you are submitting a lot of documents, so you cannot hold them in memory and need to commit them to disk. But you don't want them visible until they are all indexed.

So, instead of doing an explicit commit every X documents, have an **autoCommit** section but make sure **openSearcher** is **false**. That way the active searcher will keep pointing at the original commit point. Then, when you are all done, do a full manual commit. The changes should become visible then.

Just make sure you don't have autoSoftCommit section, because that one is not useful for you at all. That one is for people who want to see the new documents as soon as possible (with openSearcher set to true).